# DTMF during playback in Freeswitch via ESL

Tags: freeswitch

In FreeSWITCH, would it be possible to capture DTMF without interrupting sound playback? play_and_get_digits app stops playback as soon as the required keypress is obtained.

I am trying to do this via ESL, hence session.stream wouldn't work. Have tried bind_digit_action, but it doesn't work at all while the sound is being played. Lastly, bind_meta_app wouldn't work as it requires a meta keypress like *, which messes up with the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subscribe to events for a specific session and catch the DTMF events while playback or any other application is running.